# NSNotification received only by one recipient

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I have **two** `UITableViewController` objects, which represent two tabs in a tabbar view application, subscribed to a notification as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(update:) name:fileSyncStatusUpdated object:nil];
}
```

And the handler defined as follows:

```
- (void)update:(NSNotification*)notification {
}
```

Then, at some other point in my application I send the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:fileSyncStatusUpdated object:self userInfo:@{@"path": path}];
```

The problem is that only *one* object receives the notification, the other does not! To make things even more weird, if I change the handler function to be just

```
- (void)update {
}
```

and modify the `addObserver` call accordingly, then both objects receive notification.

But I still want to deliver `userInfo` to both objects..  Any idea what might be wrong? My environment is up to date.

**UPDATE**

I think I figured out the reason behind notifications not being delivered. In my explanation I will refer to sample code provided by Jageen in the comments, you can download it from here:

http://dropbox.com/s/515s3qu3a7neqb4/demoTabbar_Notification.zip?dl=0

Even though he claims that there is no problem with notifications in his code, there IS a problem :-) If you launch the app, and *immediately* click `Call notification`, then you'll see the following  output:

```
2014-12-15 12:23:32.749 demoTabbar[5019:125437] First view controller call
```

meaning that **only the first tab received notification**. The second did not receive it. Why? Because it has not been created yet! You can add `NSLog()` calls to `viewDidLoad()` to find out that only one tab is loaded when the app launches! The other tab is loaded lazily.

If you click between tabs and press `Call notification` again, you will see a different output:

```
2014-12-15 12:26:21.394 demoTabbar[5019:125437] First view controller call
2014-12-15 12:26:21.394 demoTabbar[5019:125437] Second view controller call
```

Comment: pls check it work for me https://www.dropbox.com/s/515s3qu3a7neqb4/demoTabbar_Notification.zip?dl=0

Comment: hmm, that is a weird problem. are you sure `viewDidLoad` has been called on both table view controllers at the moment where the notification is sent? otherwise you might place the `addObserver` call in `awakeFromNib` which gets called right away when your `UITabBarController` is instantiated

Comment: the other glitch that might be in your code comes from the facts that it seems you're adding the notification name as a variable, might be safer to use a _constant_ here...

Comment: Sorry for not replying over the weekend! Jageen - thanks for the sample code. In fact, there IS a problem with notifications in your example. Please see my updated post above for further details.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, try changing the notification name to a string literal that you copy/paste everywhere and see if that makes a difference.

Maybe the string variable for one of your addObserver calls is nil? (Grasping at straws here...)

I use #defined string literals for my notifications so I'm sure they are the same.

Comment: Actually, the reason is somewhat different.. It is lazy loading mechanism of UITabBar. See my updated post above for details. Thanks for help, anyway.